# Rolling sum and count in Analytical Functions

Tags: google-sheets

Look at the 2 Queries below. The Sum works but the Count does Not!! The Sum gives the Rolling numbers, but the count NOT!!

select   date_key  , product_key
, sum(product_key) SUM1
, sum (sum(product_key) ) over (order by date_key rows between 5 preceding and current row)  as ROLLINGSUM1
FROM [DYLAN 1].[dbo].[SALESFACT]
group by   date_key, product_key
order by date_key

select   date_key  , product_key
, count(product_key) countProductkey
, count (count(product_key) ) over (order by date_key rows between 5 preceding and current row)  as RollingCOUNTPRODKEY
FROM [DYLAN 1].[dbo].[SALESFACT]
group by   date_key, product_key
order by date_key

Comment: Are you sure you meant to tag this as google-sheets? It looks like a SQL query.

Comment: There is no context in which to understand this post.

Comment: Hi there @Guy0528! Please share an example Sheet that shows your actual situation and your desired result. Could you also please format the Sheet formula in a more legible way?